# How convert the data from Graphics to Bitmap in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I have some image data which is contained in Graphics object. How can I get it and put to Bitmap object, or EncodedImage object? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain a Graphics object from a Bitmap image and draw on it. Take a look at [Graphics.create](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#create%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29) for OS 4.7 and above and [the Graphics constructor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#Graphics%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29) for previous versions.

Comment: I know that I can obtain a Graphics object from a Bitmap image. But I need to obtain Bitmap from Graphics back. Can I?

Comment: How do you get that Graphics object?